# Dependency on object files which are created in different binary

Tags: c++, makefile, object-files

There are some object files say `a.o` and `b.o` created when the binary `engine` is created.

Makefile

```
.PHONY all
all: engine cars
```

Now this second binary `cars` needs .o files `a.o` and `b.o` created while creating binary `engine`

The problem here is I am using `make -j` for compilation which in some situation results in the object files not created and hence `undefined reference` errors. The issue is not seen with `make -j 5`.

Is there someway I can make it run parallely with `make -j`

Comment: "Some situtation"? Does it mean it happens at random?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with CMake?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis anything above `make -j 5` is failing as of now so I would say it is 100% reproducible which means when it runs with multiple cores the object files is not created by then

Comment: Seems a gcc bug then? It is the same with -j 2 ?

Comment: anything less than `5` works like a charm no issues seen

Comment: Please show the complete makefile.  My guess would be that you are not specifying the dependencies of target `cars` on the `.o` files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, make, even with `-j` specified, will try to build the dependencies from left to right.   So in your working case, it starts by building `engine` first, and then it builds `car`.    If engine finishes building before `car` starts, then you're fine, otherwise you're not.

In your case, I'm imagining that you have four other high level processes which are being built along with `engine`, that supersede the running of `car`, and thus `engine` happens to finish before `car` when you build with low -j values.

In any case, you are missing some dependencies.   You need either:

```
car : a.o b.o
```

if car is dependent on those two.   If `a.o` and `b.o` are side effects of the `engine` recipes, then you might do

```
car : engine
```

Note: even though your makefile happened to work with low `-j` values, Makefiles should not assume a left-to-right build order, and should not make any assumptions about running time of any recipes -- so you're makefile was indeed broken to begin with.